# При выполнении команды os.system(cmd) система не видит диакритические символы в путях к файлам (é, å, ů...)

Tags: python, cmd, shell, ос

Я выполняю функцию в python, которая передает команду в терминал. Если в пути к файлу есть диакритические символы (é, å, ů...) то получаю ошибку.

Например указываю путь: "files/input/Beyoncé - TEXAS HOLD 'EM"
Выполняю команду, которая содержит этот путь: os.system(cmd)

Ошибка:
[ERROR]: Couldn't find file at path files/input/Beyonce - TEXAS HOLD 'EM.mid

Что пробовал:

1. Использовать модуль subprocess subprocess.call(cmd_with_path, shell=True)
2. Оборачивал путь к файлу в кавычки

Система Windows 10

Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Почитайте, возможно поможет - <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180765/open-file-with-a-unicode-filename>